# Serialize nested properties as form-data with swagger-php

Tags: php, swagger, openapi, swagger-php, swagger-3.0

This is how Encoding Object Example is done in OpenApi
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md

```
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/mixed:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          id:
            # default is text/plain
            type: string
            format: uuid
          address:
            # default is application/json
            type: object
            properties: {}
          historyMetadata:
            # need to declare XML format!
            description: metadata in XML format
            type: object
            properties: {}
          profileImage:
            # default is application/octet-stream, need to declare an image type only!
            type: string
            format: binary
      encoding:
        historyMetadata:
          # require XML Content-Type in utf-8 encoding
          contentType: application/xml; charset=utf-8
        profileImage:
          # only accept png/jpeg
          contentType: image/png, image/jpeg
          headers:
            X-Rate-Limit-Limit:
              description: The number of allowed requests in the current period
              schema:
                type: integer
```

I'm trying to achive the same thing but with swagger-php.
What I don't know is how to pass `encodings` in `@OA\MediaType` to encode the `test` property as `multipart/form-data` because by default is encoded as `application/json`

EX:

```
 * @OA\Post(
 *     path="/admin/test",
 *     summary="Create new Test",
 *     description="Will attempt to create a new Test",
 *     tags={"Admin Test"},
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *          @OA\MediaType(
 *              mediaType="multipart/form-data",
 *              encoding={}
 *              @OA\Schema(
 *                  type="object",
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="test",
 *                      type="object",
 *                      description="test"
 *                      ref="#/components/schemas/MyTestSchema"
 *                  )
 *              )
 *      )
```

They have some examples here:

https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/tree/master/Examples

but I didn't found any example regarding encoding

Inside here the field is defined
https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/src/Annotations/MediaType.php

```
   /**
     * A map between a property name and its encoding information.
     * The key, being the property name, must exist in the schema as a property.
     * The encoding object shall only apply to requestBody objects when the media type is multipart or application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
     */
    public $encoding = UNDEFINED;
```

I've tried `encoding={"recommended"={"contentType"="multipart/form-data"}}` but it's useless.

Comment: Try to remove encoding={} from your example, you are setting mediaType just before it

Comment: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#encodingObject

Comment: An encoding attribute is introduced to give you control over the serialization of parts of multipart request bodies. This attribute is only applicable to multipart and application/x-www-form-urlencoded request bodies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only solution is putting all the fields:

```
 * @OA\Post(
 *     path="/admin/test",
 *     summary="Create new Test",
 *     description="Will attempt to create a new Test",
 *     tags={"Admin Test"},
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *          @OA\MediaType(
 *              mediaType="multipart/form-data",
 *              @OA\Schema(
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="test[name]",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      description="name"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="test[desc]",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      description="description"
 *                  )
 *              )
 *          )
 *      )
```